# Grouping images by time interval starting with specific position

Tags: python, image, time

I have a script which takes exif data from images, and puts it into to a list. Then I sort my list and that's what I have. It's a two dimensional array, where the first element is the timestamp and the second element is the image path:
My `img` list:

```
[[32372, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013025.JPG'], 
 [32373, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013026.JPG'], 
 [32373, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013027.JPG'],.... etc etc etc
```

The following script was made by @blhsing and groups my images. It works great, but I would like to group my images not starting from the first image, but starting from any given position.

This is the script by @blhsing:

```
groups = []
for r in img:
    if groups and r[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
        groups[-1].append(r)
    else:
        groups.append([r])
for g in groups:
    print(g[0][1], g[0][0], g[-1][0], g[-1][1])
```

And this is what I have come up with so far. It does not work well, it only takes one image and does not create a group. Could anyone help me fix it?

```
groups = []
print(iii, "iii")
#print(min_list, " my min list ")
img.sort()
cnt = 0
mili = [32372, 34880]

for n in mili:
    #print(n, "mili")
    for i in img:
        #print(i[0])
        if n == i[0]:
            if groups and i[0] - groups[-1][-1][0] <= 5:
                groups[-1].append(i)
            else:
                groups.append([i])
    for ii in groups:
        print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```

My `iii` is a list of temps:

```
[32372, 32373, 32373, 32374, 32374, 32375, 32375, 34880, 34880, 34881, 34881, 34882, 34882, 34883, 34883, 36505, 36505...etc
```

In this example I have my `min_list` with 2 positions, which means I want to create only 2 groups and classify only images starting from those 2 positions, with the same interval of 5 seconds as before.

Ps.
Thank You @pasch013 it works but check this please , why the results its like this , I get mili from min_list like this:

```
min_list.sort()
print(min_list, " min list")
interval = 5
groups = []
#mili = [1, 99]
for start_time in min_list:
    i = 0

    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time:
        i += 1
    groups.append([])
    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time + interval:
        groups[-1].append(img[i])
        i += 1
    for ii in groups:
        print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```

And that is my result: Check this out please:

```
32345 temps GOPR
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\GOPR3001.JPG path + temps 32345
32357 min
35292 temps GOPR
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam1\GOPR5405.JPG path + temps 35292
35706 min
[32357, 35706]  min list
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013002.JPG 32357 32361 F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013010.JPG
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013002.JPG 32357 32361 F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013010.JPG
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam1\G0075992.JPG 35706 35708 F:\rubish\VOL1\cam1\G0075997.JPG
```

Why I have 3 groups and not a 2 ???

Now creating a 1st group correctly but don't want to go to 2nd , have this error

```
    Z:\GOPRO\2018-05-31\VOL0102\100GOPRO\G0013002.JPG 32357 32577 Z:\GOPRO\2018-05-31\VOL0102\100GOPRO\G0013442.JPG
  File "F:/piotrwork/detectione_voltigere/GOPR_test_zero.py", line 115, in <module>
    print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My min_list is

```
[32357, 35706]  min list
```

My image list - img

```
[[32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013002.JPG'], [32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013003.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013004.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013005.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013006.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013007.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013008.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013009.JPG'], [32361, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013010.JPG'], [35706, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075992.JPG'], [35706, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075993.JPG'], [35707, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075994.JPG'], [35707, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075995.JPG'], [35708, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075996.JPG'], [35708, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075997.JPG'], [36687, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086476.JPG'],
```

And my last print

```
    32345 temps GOPR
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\GOPR3001.JPG path + temps 32345
32357 min
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/piotrwork/detectione_voltigere/GOPRO_test_zero_one.py", line 121, in <module>
    print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
35292 temps GOPR
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam1\GOPR5405.JPG path + temps 35292
35706 min
[[32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013002.JPG'], [32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013003.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013004.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013005.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013006.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013007.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013008.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013009.JPG'], [32361, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013010.JPG'], [35706, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075992.JPG'], [35706, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075993.JPG'], [35707, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075994.JPG'], [35707, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075995.JPG'], [35708, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075996.JPG'], [35708, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0075997.JPG'], [36687, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086476.JPG'], [36688, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086477.JPG'], [36688, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086478.JPG'], [36689, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086479.JPG'], [36689, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0086480.JPG'], [36690, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0086481.JPG'], [36690, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0086482.JPG'], [36691, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam1\\G0086483.JPG']]
[32357, 35706]  min list
32357
[[[32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013002.JPG'], [32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013003.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013004.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013005.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013006.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013007.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013008.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013009.JPG'], [32361, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013010.JPG']]] grrrr
35706
[[[32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013002.JPG'], [32357, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013003.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013004.JPG'], [32358, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013005.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013006.JPG'], [32359, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013007.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013008.JPG'], [32360, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013009.JPG'], [32361, 'F:\\rubish\\VOL1\\cam\\G0013010.JPG']], []] grrrr
F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013002.JPG 32357 32361 F:\rubish\VOL1\cam\G0013010.JPG
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What is the output of the first code snippet? If I run it, I get results that don't have any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
group_time = 5
groups = []
mili = [1, 99]
for start_time in mili:
    i = 0

    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time:
        i += 1
    groups.append([])
    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time + group_time:
        groups[-1].append(img[i])
        i += 1

print(groups)
```

Where `mili` is your list of starttimes and `group_time` is the size of the interval.

**Edit**

Regarding your Edit: your last two lines

```
for ii in groups:
    print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```

are inside the inner for-loop whereas I think you only want to print those once. Just unindent them and it should work as you want:

```
min_list.sort()
print(min_list, " min list")
interval = 5
groups = []
#mili = [1, 99]
for start_time in min_list:
    i = 0

    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time:
        i += 1
    groups.append([])
    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time + interval:
        groups[-1].append(img[i])
        i += 1
for ii in groups:
    print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```

**Edit 2**

If you want to have the grouping so, that all the images which have not more than 5 seconds difference to the last image are in the same group you would have to replace `start_time` with the time of the previous image in the second while loop. Just like that:

```
min_list.sort()
print(min_list, " min list")
interval = 5
groups = []
#mili = [1, 99]
for start_time in min_list:
    i = 0

    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < start_time:
        i += 1
    groups.append([])
    while i < len(img) and img[i][0] < img[i-1][0] + interval or img[i][0] < start_time + interval:
        groups[-1].append(img[i])
        i += 1
for ii in groups:
    print(ii[0][1], ii[0][0], ii[-1][0], ii[-1][1])
```